# How to add a simple button actionscript

Tags: actionscript, button, flash-cs4

I am using Adobe Flash CS4. I don't know why I do the sample actionscript code here.

```
on (release) {
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

And now I'm dealing with a button function. I already created a box then press "F8" and choose button. Now I click on the button box, and press "F9" for the actionscript.
It said that "Current selection cannot have actions applied to it"

Then choose "ActionScript 1.0 & 2.0"
Global Function > Movie Clip Control > On
** but "On" is disabled, how to solve this problem of mine to put this simple code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you changed your publish settings? Open: File -> Publish Settings, the in the Flash tab change Script to ActionScript 2.0